# Iterate over Element childrens in python

Tags: python, minidom

I usually do the following:

```
nextPreset = element.firstChild
while nextPreset != None:
    #doThings
    nextPreset = nextPreset.nextSibling
```

I was wondering if there were something like:

```
for child in element.children:
    #doThings
```

I saw a method `_get_childNodes`, but it is private...

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason for you to use DOM, please consider the `xml.etree.cElementTree` module instead. It is much faster and has a more Pythonic API

Comment: @EliBendersky I didnt know about this API. I am using it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do that several times in one project, you could use

```
def iterate_children(parent):
    child = parent.firstChild
    while child != None:
        yield child
        child = child.nextSibling
```

and then do

```
for child in iterate_children(element):
    # foo
```

Comment: Isn't `list(iterate_children(E))` the same as `E.childNodes`?

Comment: Quite possible, I didn't check. I tried to have a compact solution close to the question. But I can very well imagine that you are right.